# Mistake in the Code

Tags: extjs

```
myTree.on('click',function(node){
                 if(node.isLeaf())
                  {
                    Ext.Msg.alert("You are in value ",nodeValue,"whose name is",nodeName);
                    alert("You are in value ",nodeValue,"whose name is",nodeName);
                  }
             });
```

myTree is a TreePanel. I'm getting a tree but click function is not working. I'm very new to extjs. Help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit the post and format your code using the code sample button.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
myTree.on('click',function(node){
    if(node.isLeaf())
    {
        Ext.MessageBox.show({
            msg: 'You are in text ' + node.text + ', whose id is ' + node.id,
            buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK,
            icon: Ext.MessageBox.INFO
        });
    }
});
```

Haven't tried it, but it looks very similar to what I have been working with today :)

Answer (score 1):

You can define your tree like :

```
var myTree = new Ext.tree.TreePanel({
    region: 'west',
    id: 'navTree',
    title: 'Items',
    width: 200,
    store: store,
    split: true,
    collapsible: true,
    listeners: {
        itemclick: {
            fn: function (view, record, item, index, event) {
                //the record is the data node that was clicked
                //the item is the html dom element in the tree that was clicked
                //index is the index of the node relative to its parent

                nodeId = record.data.id;
                htmlId = item.id;

                if (record.data.leaf) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert("Alert", "leaf");
                }
                else {
                    Ext.Msg.alert("Alert", "Not leaf");
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are looking for:

```
node.value
node.name
```

OR (I'm not good with Ext)

```
node.nodeValue
node.nodeName
```